# Mass-Replacing Objects using Unity's label tags?

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, replace

Im currently working on an exercise, for which I want to create a technical design documentation.

Therefore, I need to evaluate possible solutions to a bunch of problems coming with my fictional project.

Here's a quick glance at the exercise:

The game's art & core game design are split up very harshly - basically, the core system, game mechanics and design are created to be very abstract, in order to allow them to work with a very wide variety of art settings. Also, one of the restrictions is to re-use as many assets, levels & designs as possible.

Now to my question:

I want the level designers to create levels using "template" objects (object which have all the technical features that are required, ie slots for attachments, correct scale, textures etc) and later replace these objects with set of assets I receive from my outsourcer.

Since I dont want to manually replace all objects whenever I get a new set of assets, this is what I wanted to do:

Each template object gets a descriptive label, and each asset delivered by the outsourcer needs to have the exact same label name as its corresponding template-counterpart stored in it as well (for example as a custom attribute, a channel, or simply in its name).

I now want to replace all templates with the related asset using a script.

This would be done for each set of assets. I would also keep several deployments of my engine, one per set, but initially, they'd all start out with the templates that need to be replaced (since there will need to be some modifications for each setting, both visually and from a game design perspective, keeping all assets in one trunk/project didn't make any sense to me).

To make this easier i'd use a "database" of some sorts (probably a simple dictionary which the engine script could query and which would be filled out beforehand by another script upon delivery of new assets?).

My question is: is this possible? If yes, how difficult would this be from a programmers perspective? I have only limited knowledge in this field, so I'd love to hear what you lads & ladies think about this.

Also (very important) - do you know of a better way to achieve this "replacability" of assets? Or simply have an easier way to achieve what I want to do? I appreciate any feedback! Thank you!

quick edit: This would not only be applied to 3d Objects; textures would also need to be replaced, obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Prefabs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Basically prefabs implements a sort of [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern). 
Instead of putting into scene's hierarchy directly a `GameObject` you can make it a `prefab` and put into the scene a `GameObject` that is an instance of that `prefab`.

When a `GameObject` into the scene is linked to a `prefab`, and the `prefab` will be modified, the linked object will be modified too.
If you have several instances of the same `prefab`, all istances will be updated as well.

The only strong limitation to this feature is that, since now, nested prefabs aren't supported.

> I want the level designers to create levels using "template" objects
>   (object which have all the technical features that are required, ie
>   slots for attachments, correct scale, textures etc) and later replace
>   these objects with set of assets I receive from my outsourcer.

This is the tipical use case. You have a placeholder into the scene (es. a Cube) that will be subistitued by a model when the artists will provide it.
If you instantiate 100 cubes into the scene, when you need to substitute them, you would do it manually for all objects.

If instead you have created a `prefab` (lets call it ModelPrefab) and the cubes into the scene are instances of that prefab, when you'll have the new 3d model you can simply update the `prefab` and all linked instances will be updated too.

> My question is: is this possible? If yes, how difficult would this be
>   from a programmers perspective?

If you can work without nested prefabs you have to do nothing, it's already implemented. If you need to implement `nested prefabs`, it might not be so straightforward.

> quick edit: This would not only be applied to 3d Objects; textures
>   would also need to be replaced, obviously

I made the example above using the models, but you can make a prefab from each `GameObject` that is actually a collection of Components (have a look at [Component Based Object Management](http://www.gameenginegems.net/gemsdb/article.php?id=329) if you are interested).

---

EDIT

Yes, it is possible to update prefabs throught script the required functions are in the UnityEditor namespace, so they mast be used through an editor extension. 
You can found all you need in [PrefabUtility](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html) class.

Comment: Mmyeeeea it's very close to what I want, what I'd need to know if it's possible (well, it probably is - better put: if it's not overly complicated) to access a prefab's component via script and change it to a different object? 
Basically, if I have object A as a prefab, could I access that prefab and change the path to the prefab's object to Object B ?
Doing the replacement by hand would probably work, but I'm trying to  avoid human errors as much as possible.

Comment: Also, nested prefabs will probably needed as well - The environment models will be modular and will use an "attachment" system for windows, doors and other decorations. 
I'm assuming the "not so straightforward" means there might be some bigger adjustments /modifications needed on the engine side?
Also, thanks for the link, I will have a look at it! :)